# How many pages must have iOS app?

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

I want to do some app which has one or two simple pages (views) and link to some site.
Does app store have some requirements for such kind of app?

for example:
How many pages must have such iOS app?
....

Comment: AFAIK, not in these terms. Anyway, you should read Apple's App development guidelines (once you subscribe Apple Developer Program).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no strict rule for such kind of apps.

But it is better to read following [guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html)

Answer (score 1):

Read some documentation before post this types of questions.

the iphone app is not limited by the number of pages,views or controls. App size is limited to 2GB.

Answer (score 1):

An app must have more than zero pages to pass the App Review. Any number after that is fine.